# MVC 4 ActionResult not being hit second time round

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, refresh, actionresult

We have an index page that displays rows of data.  When we go to edit a row, the Edit ActionResult is hit and presents the data for us to edit.  When we then go and commit the change the HttpPost ActionResult is hit and the data is saved.

We can return to the index page and see the saved changes but if we then try to edit the data again, the Edit ActionResult is'nt fired and we are presented with the old data until we hit F5 which then fires the Edit ActionResult and the dat is refreshed.

How can we make sure that the Edit ActionResult is hit every time without haveing to do a hard refresh?

Thanks!

Here's the edit ActionResult on the controller:

```
    [CustomAuthorizePDG]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        var model = this._db.ProductApprovals_ProductApproval.Find(id);
        if (model == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        var spServer = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SPServer"].ConnectionString;
        ViewBag.ProductStatusId = new SelectList(this._db.ProductApprovals_ProductStatus, "ProductStatusId", "ProductStatus", model.ProductStatusId);
        return View(model);
    }
```

and then the HttpPost AtionResult:

```
    [CustomAuthorizePDG]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ErrorHandler]
    public ActionResult Edit(ProductApprovals_ProductApproval model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) {
                    var sp = new ProductApprovalDataContext(new Uri("http://sp-appcentral-int/ProductApproval/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"))
                    {
                        Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
                    };

                    var productApprovalForm = sp.ProductApprovalForm.Where(x => x.ProductApprovalId == model.ProductApprovalId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (productApprovalForm != null) {
                        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        var name = string.Format("{0}{1}", model.ProductApprovalId, extension);
                        var path = string.Format("/ProductApproval/Product Approval Form/{0}", name);
                        var contentType = extension == "docx" ? "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" : "application/msword";

                        productApprovalForm.CheckedOutTo = new UserInformationListItem
                        {
                            UserName = User.Identity.Name
                        };
                        productApprovalForm.Title = fileName;
                        sp.SetSaveStream(productApprovalForm, file.InputStream, false, contentType, path);
                        sp.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);

                        this.UpdateProductApprovalWithDocument(model, path, fileName);
                    }
                }

                this._db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
                this._db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ProductStatusId = new SelectList(this._db.ProductApprovals_ProductStatus, "ProductStatusId", "ProductStatus", model.ProductStatusId);

        return View(model);
    }
```

So, when the HttpPost Edit is fired it saves the changes succesfully and they are shown in the index view.  If you then return to the Edit ActionResult you are shown the intial values until you perform a refresh.  We put a break point on the code and the second time round the Edit ActionResult isn't being fired until you hit F5...

Comment: Where are your codes? I think nobody can help you without code...

Answer (score 0):

In your HttpPost Edit action, make sure that you are doing a RedirectToAction back to the Index action. Form your problem description, it seems if you are displaying the save Edit view from the Edit action. You will want to redirect back to the Index action.

If that still does not work, inspect the HTML source of your Index view to make sure that your edit urls are still referring to Edit action methods.